# Vuex Store is in Typescript Class undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have the problem, that I want to refer a Typescript class to my `Vuex` Store. But the store is always undefined.

So this is my store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { SessionManager } from '@/classes/worker';
import { User } from '@/classes/user';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user : new User(),
    store : new SessionManager(),
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  },
  getters:{
    getUser : state => {
      return state.user;
    }
  },
});
```

And in my `SessionManager` class I want to do something like this in the constructor

```
import  store from '@/store';

        export class SessionManager {

        public constructor() {

            let user = store.state.user as User;
            console.log(store);

        }
    }
```

I have the Vue-Extensions for Chrome. So when I set a Break point in Chrome in the line before I use the store, and watch the state of the store in the extension he already exist.

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(store);`?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag this line is never be hit because I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". When I only say let user = store, than console.log(store) show the output "undefined"

Comment: can you comment out that first? and just log the `store` to console?

Comment: it could be that you are experiencing problem with ESM.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag so I have to write my store in Typescript too?

Comment: Can you show your log first please?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag What log do you mean? Consol.log shows „undefined“ when I only log the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a cyclic dependency: your store file is calling `new SessionManager()` before it calls `new Vuex.Store`, so when the `SessionManager` constructor runs, the store has not yet been created and exported.  I guess you should avoid accessing the store from the `SessionManager` constructor.  I don't know Vuex, so there may be another way this is supposed to be done.

To understand what is happening, let's look at a simplified version of the code:

```
let store;
class SessionManager {
    constructor() {
        console.log(store);
    }
}
let sm = new SessionManager();
store = new Vuex.Store({state: {store: sm, ...}, ...});
```

At the time `new SessionManager()` runs, `store` has not been initialized yet, so it is `undefined`.

Comment: thank you for your help. I thought that when the store is created, SessionManager and user are created to. But is it not this way?

Comment: See the updated answer.  The argument to the constructor of `Vuex.Store` has to be evaluated before the constructor can be called.  Thus, the `SessionManager` is created _before_ the `Vuex.Store`.